# Training Perceptrons with Backprop

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, perceptron

Is it possible to train a simple perceptron with a threshold activation function such as this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron with Backpropagation instead of the perceptron rule?

is it a problem that threshold functions are not defined around 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. In order to use backprop you have to have non-zero derivatives of the function. Derivative of the step function is zero everywhere.

Comment: The derivative of step function does not exist around the threshold value.